# BigInt or varchar(40) and autoincrement id or no id? SQL

Tags: php, mysql

My company is going to do a Follow system for a web forum.
This forum has more than 1 million members and one can follow other member to see this members posts on the forum.

First I did a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `following` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `following` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My office friend told me that I should use USER ID instead of the username  in `user` (person who follow) and `following` (the other one)  row. Is he right?

question 1: Is better in this way use BigInt unsigned instead of Varchar and work with user ID instead of the username?

question 2: He also told me that I should remove id auto_increment, since I don't use it (I insert users and remove using where user='$user' and following='$following'). Is he right? or auto_increment is important?

Thank you friends!

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are not the same thing. Your question appears to be only about MySQL, so you should remove the irrelevant tag. Also, you really should try looking for a tutorial first. These questions are extremely basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think? Is it more efficient to compare eight-byte keys (`BIGINT`) or varying-length 40-byte keys (`VARCHAR(40)`)? Clearly, the `BIGINT` key will be more efficient. Yes, for the sake of DBMS efficiency you should use `BIGINT` or even `INT` values as unique identifiers for your users. `INT` will be enough. If you actually acquire more than 2 x 10**9 users you'll have a Facebook sized problem and a Facebook sized budget. Until then, get your project working. [YAGNI](http://blog.codinghorror.com/kiss-and-yagni/).

Is this table you're describing intended to implement a straightforward many-to-many relationship between users and other users? Can a follower follow a user more than once? If not, get rid of the surrogate primary key in this table (the autoincrementing ID). Instead, make your primary key a composite of the user_id and following_id columns.

If this were my project I'd make `(user_id, follower_id)` the primary key, and I'd also create an index on `follower_id`.  (If MyISAM is the access method the second index should be on `(follower_id, user_id)`.) There's no need for another index besides the primary key, it's entirely redundant.

Comment: thank you for your answer! just one more question, is better for me use primary key as a composite of user and following or an UNIQUE KEY `user_following` (`user`,`following`)?